# Unwanted outline on border when parent is transformed

Tags: css, rendering, border, css-transforms

I am using borders on some content. However, I am finding an unwanted 1px outline the same color as the `background` color is being added around the border when the parent is transformed (at least with `scale` and `rotate`). This occurs on pseudo-elements of the children as well

```
.container { 
    transform:rotate(-45deg); 
}
.child {
    border:3px solid white; background:green;
}
```

[**jsFiddle to work with**](http://jsfiddle.net/ayFbD/)

I have tested on the newest Chrome and IE, the problem is on both

How can I get rid of this outline without using `box-shadow` or removing the transform?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a translateZ(1px)

```
.container { 
    position:absolute; 
    top:50%; left:50%; 
    -webkit-transform:translateZ(1px) rotate(-45deg); 
    transform:rotate(-45deg); 
}
```

(not really sure why does this work ...)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayFbD/3/)

Seems that IE needs more fixing...

```
.container { 
    position:absolute; 
    top:50%; left:50%; 
    -webkit-transform:translateZ(1px) rotate(-45deg); 
    transform:perspective(999px) translateZ(1px) rotate(-45deg); 
}
```

[fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/ayFbD/6/)

Comment: All this tricks (and the backface-visibility in other answers) work similarly, engaging a more accurate render in the graphics engine (and sometimes making it rendered by the GPU). However, it's always a matter of trial and error. The usual tricks are forcing a 3d transform (sometimes it is enough with translateZ(0px)), setting a pespective, and setting backface visibility hidden

Answer (score 3):

Not a great fix, but adding `backface-visibility: hidden;` which determines if the element should be visible or not when it's faced away from the screen, commonly used when you "flip" and element, seems to fix it, at least in Chrome. I haven't got the possibility to test in IE though.

The reason I tried it is because this "hack" has solved simliar issues that I've had before. But I'm not really sure why it works ...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayFbD/2/)

Answer (score 0):

In chrome you should be able to use `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to fix this. I'm not too sure about IE, I don't have anything to test that on right now.

http://jsfiddle.net/ayFbD/4/