# Why is there a border around modal box header?

Tags: css

Appears in latest version of chrome - am I missing something? I can't see a reason for this border; it appears above, to the left, and most prominently to the right of the element:

[image: Sample image]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o63u2bmz/2/)

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFBF76;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  border: 3px solid #FFBF76;
  background: #FFF1BD;
  overflow: auto;
  border-radius: 0px;
  outline: none;
}

.modalBackground {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0px;
  background-color: #00000066;
}
```

```html
<div class="modalBackground">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="header">
      My Header
    </div>
    <div>
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

Tried applying both suggestions, to limited success. Even with the new flex based approach ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o63u2bmz/5/)) the result is the same.

Comment: I don't see that issue in the fiddle..?

Comment: Browser/version? Maybe Chrome specific issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some invalid / unnecessary properties set leaving it to interpretation by the browsers which could render different accordingly like for example `border-radius` would be `0` instead of with `px`, `inset` wouldn't apply to a fixed position element, and a hex `color` is only 6 digits (if you want an alpha channel for opacity go with `rgba` instead) etc.

Anyway, made some edits to your example, you should no longer see the issue, hope it helps. Cheers!

```css
.header {
  background-color: #FFBF76;
  text-align: center;
  margin: -1px; /* ensure no resize space */
}
.modal {
  border: 3px solid #FFBF76;
  background: #FFF1BD;
}
.modalBackground {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #000066;
}
```

```html
<div class="modalBackground">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="header">
      My Header
    </div>
    <div>
    some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- <asd></asd> = not a valid element -->
```

Comment: Yeah it was just copy/pasted mostly from what I was using; this doesn't answer "why is the border there" but instead "how can I not have a border", but I think the former is simply "bug related to transform in chrome" sadly.

Comment: I tried this, without success - I thought it was due to the transform, but seems to still be a problem using a version of your code (edited into original question). Even executing your snippet in SO can repro the problem, though it requires zooming in. I've notice resizing the window causes the problem to come and go as well...

Comment: @Rollie I didn't test resizing, see updates snippet, added a simple negative 1px margin to ensure no phasing from resizing. Cheers

Comment: Sadly it seems to just shift it left - still leaves the background color on the right side

Comment: @Rollie just increase the negative margin. You're going to notice render defects often when using the browser scaling to enlarge your elements like that. I'm not able to reproduce your current observation on my end even up to 500% though ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the `transform: translate(-50%,-50%) translate3d(0,0,0);` on the modal class. Why not use a flex display for your modal? You would not have to rely on positioning and transform hacks to get the element centered.

```css
body {
  margin: auto;
}

.header {
  width: 100%; /* <-- removed, already a block level element */
  background-color: #FFBF76;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
}
.modal {
  /* position: absolute; <-- removed */
  /* left: 50%; <-- removed */
  /* top: 50%; <-- removed */
  /* transform-style: preserve-3d; <-- removed */
  /* transform: translate(-50%,-50%) translate3d(0,0,0); <-- removed */
  border: 3px solid #FFBF76;
  background: #FFF1BD;
  overflow: auto;
  /* border-radius: 0px; <-- no need to specify 0px, is by default */
  outline: none;
}
.modalBackground {
  /* position: fixed; <-- removed */
  display: flex; /* <-- added */
  justify-content: center; /* <-- added */
  align-items: center; /* <-- added */
  width: 100vw; /* <-- added */
  height: 100vh; /* <-- added */
  /* inset: 0px; <-- removed */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) /* typo? #00000066*/ 
}
```

```html
<div class="modalBackground">
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="header">
      My Header
    </div>
    <div>
    some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why set a viewport relation height/width on a fixed position element?

Comment: Just used one of oh so many answers related to "how to do this in css" that looked clean/simple. As with the other answer, this doesn't explain "why is there a border..." but provides a reasonable alternative.

Comment: Related to your answer - what is the 'type' comment about? I think that value is correct, no?

Comment: The 'border' is there in Chrome because of the transform rule that is set in the CSS, remove it using teh OPs initial code and see for yourself, as to why that causes it, I am not sure.

Comment: @ChrisW. I had initially removed that from the CSS, edited my answer...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004108/unwanted-outline-on-border-when-parent-is-transformed this may give some insight into the issue in chrome... --> *All this tricks (and the backface-visibility in other answers) work similarly, engaging a more accurate render in the graphics engine (and sometimes making it rendered by the GPU). However, it's always a matter of trial and error. The usual tricks are forcing a 3d transform (sometimes it is enough with translateZ(0px)), setting a pespective, and setting backface visibility hidden – vals*

Comment: Ya, but with a 95vh/vw you'll introduce a margin space around the modal background, not sure if that's intentional or not, there's some other things in there too but figured we'd all learn something :)

Comment: @ChrisW. There that's much better ;) And yes ALWAYS learning!

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work as is due to some nuance of positioning in the library I'm using (react-modal). I edited using a similar version from ChrisW, but can still repro the problem.